# Can I get Django multiple admin sites, users, databases in a webapp?

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-admin

I have a web app that is now working for a single business. It has users, a database, an admin site that the owner uses, and a few frontend pages through which the employees access it.

I am planning to scale and the first idea was using several Django instances as subdomains (that way I just had to duplicate the code and manage routeing), but I soon realised that it would be pretty resource intensive.

Is there are a way I can have multiple organizations use the webapp? All of them have the same use case so it should be less complex. I intensively use the Django users app for authentication and as a foreign key in databases so just cannot do without separate admin, users, and database for each business.

The point where I encounter major issues is when trying to get different users for each of the business.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: I just thought about another workaround, though it will take A LOT of coding. *Basically making the Django admin by myself.* I just need 3-4 functions out of admin: authentication, viewing models, adding users, and downloading databases in xls format. Is there a way I can do the authentication of admin and adding users part? For viewing databases, maybe I can just assign a key in the models to understand which business the row belongs to.

Comment: This is in essence what a multi-tenant webserver does: https://github.com/citusdata/django-multitenant